# The MySQL adapter mysqli is not available - how to resolve this issue?

Tags: mysql, sql, server, server-configuration

My website [www.EliteMaths.com.au](http://www.EliteMaths.com.au) has been active until early this week. When I tried to access it this morning I got the following error message:

**Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: The MySQL adapter mysqli is not available**

How can I fix this issue? The following screenshots are from the web hosting.
When I click on the orange "control panel" button, I get an error message.

[image: Web hosting]

[image: error message]

I have not updated anything nor made any changes from Joomla end or in the web hosting or domain. So I don't quite understand how this would have happened. Has someone tamper with any of my system?

Many thanks

Comment: What kind of server you are using? Is it shared, VPS or dedicated? Do you have access to php.ini file? If yes than enable the mysqli through php.ini by removing semicolon before this statement `extension=php_mysqli.dll`. Next restart apache.

Comment: I would suggest contacting your hosting provider. It doesn't sound like it's an issue with your site, but the server instead.

Comment: @Will This question remains "open" (abandoned).  If one or more of the supplied suggestions provides a solution, please mark the "best" one with a green tick so that the system deems your question to be resolved and future researchers will know that at least one of the posts contains a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error after a reboot on one site of 12 on my server. All my sites are Joomla. We recently upgraded to php7.1 I tried everything then found the fix.

The fix was to comment out the suPHP line in .htaccess. 
Remember to show hidden files to find the .htaccess in the root.

DirectoryIndex index.php

```
#<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
#  suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myusername/public_html/yourJ3folder
#  <Files php.ini>
#    order allow,deny

#    deny from all
#  </Files>
#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your hosting company made some modifications on their server or moved you to another server that doesn't have the MySQLi adapter. You can either edit the configuration.php and change `$dbtype` to `mysql` (from `mysqli`), and see if that works, or, ideally, contact your host and tell them about this problem (they should be able to fix it since it is on their end).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the server configuration has changed, either by your hosting provider or it could be you - if for example you switched the php handler for your hosting.

What this error says is that the mysqli isn't available in your current php setup, but your Joomla configuration relies on it to connect to the database.

You could try to change this manually in the configuration.php

change

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
```

to:

```
public $dbtype = 'pdomysql';
```

or if that won't work again to:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
```

In any case report this to your hosting provider and ask them for more information, as to what has changed (if it was not you) and why you weren't informed.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error on my Joomla site. I contacted the hosting provider and they got a specialist onto it and fixed it within minutes. The fix was simple: just delete the MySQL database USER password and reset with a new password. The site came back up instantly. Hope this helps.